# MUI Grid system spacing issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The more spacing value the more it doesn't fit to the parent element. I don't think that I missed some configuration. I guess this is bug, I found a negative weird margin from the CSS. `margin-left: -40px;`.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

[image]

This is the code:

```
<Grid
  container
  className="experiences"
  spacing={5}
  sx={{ background: "#333" }}
>
  {experienceFields.map((item, index) => (
    <Grid item key={item.id} style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item lg={6}>
          <RenderField
            control={control}
            name={`experiences.${index}.title`}
            label="Position"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item lg={6}>
          <RenderField
            control={control}
            name={`experiences.${index}.company`}
            label="Company Name"
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  ))}
</Grid>
```